How do I set multiple options for the server.open config in Vite.js?
How do I set multiple options for the server.open config in Vite?
I want to open a specific page in Vite and also in multiple specific browsers when running npm run dev, but it seems the server.open config only takes a boolean or a string. Adding 'google chrome' alone as the string will open Chrome, but not the default page as it would if the server.open config were not set.
The Vite docs say to:

See the open package for more details.

but I can't seem to access all of that power using server.open.

You don't. As Vite's doc says, you either pass a boolean (whether or not to open the default browser on the app's homepage) or a string (the pathname, not which browser - it also tells you how to set an env var to choose which browser).

@jonrsharpe - Also tried the env approach which I could not get to work, but either way that also won't let me load to multiple browsers it seems since you can only set a string as the value of the env variable. Dev environments seem way too hard to me.
